# ES6 module support in Chrome 62/Chrome Canary 64, does not work locally, CORS error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, module, ecmascript-6, same-origin-policy

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="module">
        import {answer} from './code.js'
        console.info("It's ${answer()} time!")
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

code.js

```
export function answer(){
    return 'module';
}
```

> Error: Access to Script at 'file:///C:*******/es6/code.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Chrome says it can support modules and I have seen examples working on the web, but when I copy them of download and run them locally, I always get the error above.  I do not want to use Babel, Webpack, etc.

I have tried enabling the Experimental Web Platform features flag in both Chrome and Chrome Canary.

Answer (score 57):

Unlike regular scripts, ES6 modules are subject to [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). This means that you cannot `import` them from the file system or cross-origin without a CORS header (which cannot be set for local files).

Basically you need to run this code from a (local) server or disable same-origin in the browser for testing (do not do this permanently). See: [Access to Image from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965066/access-to-image-from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy).

Comment: Thanks Alexander!!!

Any idea what will happen if I try to use electron?

Comment: @markpavlis I would guess Electron does not have such security restrictions, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Also: 
When importing modules, the string that specifies the location of the module is called the “module specifier” or the “import specifier”.

Have a look at the valid and supported Module specifiers (from './lib.mjs' is valid, but not from 'lib.mjs'). 

Check: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules

Different specifiers will be allowed soon.

Comment: Useful, after a day spent searching for a reason why my module wouldn't load, I ran the code from a local node server. Result. No-one makes this obvious but easily-overlooked point out there in the JS wild :-)

Comment: If you don't have time to setup a local server, you can simply use: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I've one doubt though, luckily I was reading your answer https://security.stackexchange.com/a/201313 but can't understand how a local file request from local itself is not same-origin?

Comment: @user7630232 I believe that would be because `file://` protocol is treated as an [*opaque origin*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#file_origins) and it never passes the same-origin test and thus leads to a CORS error.

Answer (score 18):

I've run in the same problem, trying to import es6 code to launch in a html file in my browser, getting CORS errors in my browser console. If you have python on your machine one easy way to create a local server is to:

`python3 -m http.server 8001`

From the folder your are working in.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue**
[image: Issue]

**Resolution**

Looks like you're trying to open the web-page locally (via `file:`// protocol) i.e. double clicking the `.html` file. Unfortunately modules only work via HTTP(s), so all you need to do is use a local web server. Popular choices include:

- [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer), a VS Code extension that adds a right-click option to run your pages with a local server.
- [Node static server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-server#getting-started), a simple http server to serve static resource files from a local directory.
- [Node live server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server/v/0.8.0) is easy to install and use:
- [Lite-Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server): BrowserSync does most of what we want in a super fast lightweight development server. It serves the static content, detects changes, refreshes the browser, and offers many customizations.

  ```
  npm install -g live-server // Install globally via npm

  live-server                // Run in the html's directory
  ```

Or even shorter and without altering your packages:

```
npx live-server
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run any chromium based browser with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag to make importing from modules work locally through the `file://` protocol.