# Why does console throw a error while working with modules?

Tags: javascript, module

I'm learning JavaScript concretely modules and I want to test everything I have learned about modules, but when I'm connecting file it and running it throws an error and I don't understand why.

Here is the error:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Modules</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

First JS file:

```js
export const module = {
  one: "one",
  second: "second",
  third: "third"
};
```

Second JS file:

```js
import {module} from "./modules.js";

console.log(module);
```

Please say what is wrong and what should I do?

Comment: This guy seems to have encountered the same error,,, seems like he approved the solution you could also try it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919331/access-to-script-at-from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy

Comment: You must be opening the `.html` file directly in the browser. This would throw the `CORS` error. You could try setting up a local server and serve the whole project directory. You can use `live-server` npm package for creating the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very clear to show error message in your console.

You should run a web server (e.g. nginx) and put files to correct folder based on server defined to use HTTP request for running it.

EX: Run a simple node.js server

1. Create **package.json** and install express package.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
}
```

2. Write a very simple **server.js** file.

**server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html', err => {
        if (err) res.send(404);
    });
});

app.get(/(.*)\.(js)/i, (req, res) => { // it also can add other filenames extension
    res.sendfile(__dirname + "/" + req.params[0] + "." + req.params[1], err => {
        if (err) res.send(404);
    });
});


app.listen(3000, () => { // port can be modified
    console.log('Listening on port 3000!');
});
```

3. Put all your files and the above files in the same folder.
4. Run **npm start** or **node server.js** to launch server.

Comment: Can i use Node.js?

Comment: I add a simple example for you.