# How do I get around Cross Origin Requests being blocked?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve a file, on the server that I run my php on.  A web hosting service.

I've encountered this problem before, trying to access a file from html either locally, or from a server.  My code is:

```
<! DOCTYPE html >

<html>
   <head>
       <title>retrieve_activities_json.html</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   
       <p id="demo"></p>
       
       <script>
       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if( this.readystate == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {
               var activities_obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
               document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = activities_obj[0];
           }
   
       };
   
       xmlhttp.open("GET","activities.json", true);
       xmlhttp.send();
       
       </script>
   </body>

</html>
```

Is there any settings to my browser, or to the webhosting server that will help me defeat this error message:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/Web%20Development%20Tutorials/JavaScript%20Practice/activities.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Comment: CORS is setup on the server.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing `Origin 'null'` means that you're trying to dynamically load files from your local machine.  This is not allowed by the [Same-Origin Polciy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) (CORS) that Chrome is telling you about.  Chrome is particularly strict on this rule.

While there are [ways to get around it](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/09/disable-same-origin-policy/), I really wouldn't recommend it.

Your best bet would be to set up a [free, local web server](https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-local-web-server-all-platforms/) and run your test code from there.

Comment: I don't know, if it makes a difference to your answer, but, as I state above, the file that I'm trying to load is on my webhosting server, it's not a file stored locally on my PC.  It seems that I've gotten this to work before, when trying AJAX examples.  I have an AJAX script that does this successfully from a git server.  I'll play around with that and see if I can get it to download a file from my webhosting's server.

Comment: Hmm, you should probably use a fully qualified path in your ajax query then: `xmlhttp.open("GET","https://localhost/activities.json", true);`

Comment: Oh, now I see why you're saying this.  Since I couldn't access the file from my webhostings server, my code above is my second attempt to access it, on my local server.  Sorry for the confusion. This was my original line of code: xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://signup.travisknights.org/get_activities_json.php", true);  But, it did not work as well.  I've played with a couple of AJAX tutorials that have worked in the past, substituting the file path above.  In all instances the same result, the same error message.

Comment: I can see, by searching many resources regarding COR policies,  that, ostensibly for security purposes, AJAX is no longer possible, unless set up so by the owner of the server that offers access to JSON data.  What a nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

For linux

```
google-chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="/tmp/someFolderName"
```

https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-fix-error-access-to-script-at-from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-http-data-chrome-chrome-extension-chrome-u/#google_vignette

https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-fix-error-access-to-script-at-from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-http-data-chrome-chrome-extension-chrome-u/

[Access to Script at ' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919331/access-to-script-at-from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy)