# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module using reactjs CDN Links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, frontend

I am writing an app in Reactjs using react CDN Links, not 'npx create-react-app'. I have created an index.html, index.js, and App.js files. I want to import the App.js component in Index.js file using `import App from '../components/App.js'` but it is giving "can not use import statement outside module" error on the browser (client-side). following are the codes

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Notepad Web App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <!-- React CDN -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    <!-- JSX -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>


    <!-- External JS File -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**INDEX.JS**

```
import App from '../components/App.js'
const e = React.createElemnt;
ReactDOM.render(e(App), document.querySelector('#root'));
```

**APP.JS**

```
const e = React.createElement;

function App()
{
    return(
        e("h1",{},'This is React App')
    )
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include a JavaScript module in an HTML page, you have to tell that to the browser explicitly by adding `type="module"`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
```

You can read more about modules and how to use them [here](https://v8.dev/features/modules).

**EDIT:**

Regarding the new error you get, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46992592/2566065):

> Unlike regular scripts, ES6 modules are subject to [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). This means that you cannot `import` them from the file system or cross-origin without a CORS header (which cannot be set for local files).

> Basically you need to run this code from a (local) server.

You can use [live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server):

1. Install it by running:

```sh
npm install -g live-server
```

2. Run in your website folder:

```sh
live-server
```

3. Open http://localhost:8080 in your browser, and your site will work

Comment: By applying the changes suggested by you, now I am facing following error on browser.  ` Access to script at 'file:///home/ubuntu/Desktop/projects/notepad/public/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Answer (score 1):

Changing the type to`"module"` can solve the issue like this:

`<script  type="module" src="./index.js"></script>`

Also, you have a syntax error `line 2` in index.js `const e = React.createElemnt;` you have a missing `e` in the word `Elemnt`.