# Unable to import Axios 1.x.x in ReactJS, Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

With the simplest React app, I can't import `axios` without seeing this error in my console:

`bundle.js:45314 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I created a base app with `create-react-app` and installed a few packages:

```bash
npx create-react-app my-app

# Inside 'my-app/':
yarn install
yarn add axios
```

(I ran `yarn install` again just in case.)

I added `import axios from "axios"` to the default `App.js` file as shown here:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios"; // Here is the problem.

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

With `axios` imported, I get a blank screen and the error message I mentioned above.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62733772/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-using-reactjs) wanted me to add a line to `index.html`, but it didn't do anything for me. Maybe I added it in the wrong place? Here is the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
```

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import) recommended the same line, or adding `"type": "module"` to `package.json`, but that also had no affect.

I was using React 18 when I encountered this problem, but I had a working React app using React 17. I switched `"react"` and `"react-dom"` to `"^17.0.0"` in `package.json`, but it didn't help, either.

---

*Update 2022-11-18:*

This is a problem specifically with Axios 1.x.x, and I can "solve" the problem by switching back to a 0.x.x version (0.27.2 is working for me).

Most developers seem to experience it with their Jest tests; see this [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5026) and this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73958968/cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-with-axios). The latter was the most informative, but did not solve my problem.

I am not trying to run tests (yet). I'm just trying to use axios in my React app. I can revert to 0.x.x, or I can try using `fetch` instead. But I would like to understand the source of the problem. I.e. I'd like to understand the implications of this statement:

> The 1.x.x version of axios changed the module type from CommonJS to ECMAScript.

- ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74079349/10642417))

Has anyone been able to make Axios 1.x.x work in a React app?

Comment: Not an answer to your question - but if you are just starting a new project, use Next.js instead of CRA, it is significantly better.

Comment: @JK. `next` and `cra` are totally different things and can't be used interchangeably

Comment: @D.Hammaker how do you run the app?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I just use `yarn start` to run it. Not building or anything.