# JavaScript module on browser

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

catalog

```
 - folder
  - index.html
  - index.js
  - index1.js
```

index.html

```html
   <!-- main content --->
   <script type='module' src='./index.js'></script>
```

index.js

```js
   import {show} from "./index1"

   show();
```

index1.js

```js
   export default function show(){
       console.log('hello world');
   }
```

### descripttion

when run index.html on browser, is don't work, and i got this error:

`Access to script at 'file:///Users/xxx/Documents/code/canvas/test/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

[image: browser error]

it may work with server, how to make it work without server, moulti-module.

import a module from other. just like run with nodejs env.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access to Image from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965066/access-to-image-from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing a script as a `module`: File should export as `module.exports`

Please refer to the below link for working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mgwfrd

Comment: I am sorry, your demo run correct， but not work at localhost， the error msg `Access to script at 'file:///Users/br/Documents/code/demo_canvas/demo10/fileHandler.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`