# Import IO module on web browser Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, module, io

In an attempt to answer this question myself, I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59386512/javascript-module-on-browser) answer but ended up getting a similar error.

My current file structure is

```
-index.html
-imports.js
-script.js
-style.css
```

In `imports.js`, from the question listed earlier, I have

```
function show() {
  console.log('Hello, World!');
}

module.exports = {show}
```

as a test.

In my `index.html` file, I have `<script type='module' src='./imports.js'></script>` in order to link to my `imports.js` file. And in my `scripts.js` file, again as a test, I have

```
import {show} from "./imports.js";

show();
```

However, when running this, I get thrown the errors

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at /script.js:3:1
ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at /imports.js:4:2
```

As my title states, I am trying to import the `IO` module, but when I kept getting errors, I went back to test a more basic approach. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: script.js has to be a module `<script src="script.js" type="module"`

Comment: The rest of my code doesn't work if I change it to that.

Comment: It runs, but just does not work.