# Fetch to API returning 'from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy'

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am using the following JavaScript to perform an API call and do different things depending on the response:

```
const passwordApiUrl = 'https://www.test.net/youin/api/password/'

// When RESET button clicked
function onReset() {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const resetCode = urlParams.get('resetcode');
    const password = $('#txtPassword').val();

    const apiPath = passwordApiUrl + resetCode;
    alert(apiPath);
    sendPostRequest(apiPath, password)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.status);
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                // Error
                alert('error');
            } else {
                // Fine
                alert('pass');
            }
        })
}

async function sendPostRequest(url, data) {
    return await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
}
```

This is the full error message in the console -

> Access to fetch at 'https://www.test.net/youin/api/password/b0dBNnFlVVQ0TWorZklTbnBreGdkYnZLMlF2MTJ0R3g2VEd3RlZRa2Jia3lLeWNRVkpGTW5oVkw1K3hqR01xa3dUZWtrWFVzQmhLVEFSU280SFlaS2F4OTdLalg2Z1p1dFg5YU9YN3huTzA9' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Any advice on how to fix?

Comment: Cors problem is for server side not for client side. What is your backend?

Comment: A bunch of answers are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965066/access-to-image-from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy