How to correctly import JS modules?
I want to parse ini file
Here is my html code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="module" src="parseINIFile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

and parseINIFile.js :
import {parse} from "ini";

console.log(parse("name=name\nage=age"));

it gives 2 errors:
1)
Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/JS/parseINIFile.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
2) Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
instead it should give me object {name : name, age : age}.
I tried to use require:
const {parse} = require("ini");

console.log(parse("name=name\nage=age"));

but it doesn't change.
Sorry for English.

You need to place your files in a server. Do you have nodejs installed?

Also, the error seems to be obvious what the problem is. You are using the wrong protocol scheme. To fix the problem, you can create a server using node.js through express and place your files in a public directory by using the static middleware provided by express. Then, place your static files in that directory, like your imported JS file.

Seems to be a CORS error
Check out this post for further explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41965272/10906594

Hi, this isn't a CORS error. The file is opened from local disk, so no JS allowed
